# To delete an old unanswered post and reopen a same one with updated information?

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to delete an old post and reopen a same one but with updated information?

I posted a question around 6 months ago, but until this moment there is still no valid answer to it. I figured out a method to bypass the issue later, but the root cause to the problem in my post has not been found yet.

Recently I have more information about the problem and want to update the post, but I am worried that this post is so old that its updates won't get noticed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should edit the question and add the new information in the question. It wil get renewed attention because of this.

You can see this here, for instance: [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: The reason for the renewed attention it's because when editing a question you actually bump it to the top pages. Although it isn't outright disallowed to create multiple *identical* questions, editing prevents duplication and improves the signal-to-noise ratio of the site. Also, deleting several questions can prevent you from posting on the site.